# How to move a 64bit pointer into the RAX register?

Tags: gcc, 64-bit, inline-assembly

I have the following code in a GNU C program:

```
void *segment = malloc(1024);
asm volatile("mov $%0, %%rax" : : "r" (segment));
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error: illegal immediate register operand %rax
```

What is wrong with `%rax`?

Comment: What's wrong with the code ... there's _never_ a need to explicitly move anything into `%rax` directly, because you can instead do `asm("" : : "a"(segment));` - i.e. use the register modifier `"a"` to say "I'm expecting this value to be passed/returned in `[ER]AX`". The above assembly is meaningless - the compiler will throw it out. Please clarify what you want to do with the value in `RAX`.

Answer (score 0):

While FrankH's points are valid, strictly speaking cause of this error is the dollar sign.  Dollar signs in assembler are used to denote constants.  So "mov $1, %%eax" would work.  However, your code generates:

```
mov $%rax, %rax
```

$%rax is meaningless and generates a error.  This will resolve the error:

```
void *segment = malloc(1024);
asm volatile("mov %0, %%rax" : : "r" (segment));
```

Since malloc will return its value in rax, this will (most likely) generate "mov %rax, %rax".

In other words, it will still be meaningless, unsafe and inefficient, but it will compile without error.

Assuming this code is intended to be more than an experiment to teach you something about using asm, you will need to provide more details to get a more useful answer.